# Primefaces & IE9 rendering issue

Tags: jsf, primefaces, internet-explorer-9

We have some annoying rendering issue with Primefaces 2.2.1 & IE9. There seems to be some kind of "two step rendering" after certain ajax updates.

1. In the first step, the ajax-updated code is rendered without the proper css applied to it - this looks messy, like so: [image: First step: ugly]
2. In the second step, the proper css is applied and everything looks as expected, like so: [image]

Not all ajax updates have this rendering issue, but we have a hard time sorting out what triggers this behaviour.

If you have any ideas or hints, please let me know, since this is really annoying & ugly.

Regards: jimmy

Comment: Is it consistent?  Does this behavior change if you switch IE from/to Local Intranet Zone?  Is there a script error on the page?  What browser mode is running when you run the IE Developer Tools (F12)?

Comment: Yes, it's reproducible, it happens every time when a certain part of the view is updated via ajax. It also does not depend on the zone the site is in. There is no script error and ie is running in ie9/standard mode.

Comment: you are going to need to post some markup and code